# React.JS notifications

Tags: reactjs

I have a user story that I am trying to fulfill, but the only part I am not certain is that they want the user to be notified when their inspection is past due, and a reminder when the inspection is due.
I found notifications on react native, but I am not using native. Any ideas or pointers on how to task this? It would be my first time doing it and I am still reactively new to React.

Comment: You can use the `alert` function in JS to kinda display a notification

Comment: Maybe you can use push notification? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API